# CSS Where to put element position code for each page?

Tags: html, css

I know that css if for styling looks of buttons etc... but what about when I position elements? Each page has different element positions/elements. Does it make sense to create an id for each element on every page and position in main css file?

Comment: You can always make few stylesheets and apply them for each page.

Comment: @K.Daniek You don't think that would become unmanageable on a big website?

Comment: Of course it will.

Answer (score 0):

When designing a page it is very important to separate the *content* (e.g. HTML) from the *style* (e.g. CSS). A well-structured webpage should be able to be read out loud and still make sense.

In this context, the position of the elements should be defined in relevance to other elements and not to the whole page. These elements can also be assigned to a *class* (e.g. `<div class="announcement">`).

This gives you a lot of power, since you can define a different behavior not only for the class (or id) but also for the class in respect to the parent classes. Take these scenarios for example:

Scenario 1:

```
<div class="post-content">
    <div class="announcement">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

Scenario 2:

```
<div class="special-content">
    <div class="announcement">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

The main css rule for the "announcement" can be the same. But you can have a special rule for the "announcement" that is inside a "special-content" area. So, you can just add another rule for the properties that should be different. Not only position, but anything:

```
.announcement {
    color: red;
}

.post-content .announcement {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.special-content .announcement {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Of course you can build similar relations with classes, ids or standard elements. Read more about selectors in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).